# How can I disable/decrease the number of calls to getAuthTimeout?

Tags: users, session, timeout

The host of a client is claiming the call to getAuthTimeout is triggering their firewall, and in turn blocks my client from accessing their site for a longer duration.

Is there a way to disable or change the interval?

Comment: An extra request every 60 seconds is above their threshold?

Comment: @ Brad: seriously. An extra getAuthTimeout every minute?  If a company is that concerned about security, they should whitelist the remote IP.  Or use a remote VPN connection. I've gotten brute force attempts on my WP installs at 500+/requests second.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that the support person said it was triggering every couple milliseconds, which I have no reason to believe is true. I've asked them for logs and more details, but in general they have been very vague and incompetent in their answers, so I don't know what to believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the AJAX call to `getAuthTimeout` is [hard coded](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/resources/js/craft.js#L7057) to fire every 60 seconds. In other words, if you're looking for a [config value](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings), there isn't one – might be worth a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests)?

For a quickfix/hack, you can create a [custom plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) and add the following to its `init` method:

```
craft()->templates->includeJs('(function () {
    Craft.AuthManager.checkInterval = 600; // Ten minutes
}());', true);
```

You can change the `600` to any number of seconds, of course.

If you want to kill the timeout check *completely*, you can do this instead of the above:

```
craft()->templates->includeJs('(function () {
    Craft.AuthManager.prototype.setCheckAuthTimeoutTimer = function () {};
}());', true);
```

Of course, both of these snippets are total hacks. Use with caution!

One important thing to note is that I don't think its possible to stop the *first* AJAX call to `getAuthTimeout` (which will fire after 60 seconds). The reason is that by the time the JavaScript hack inside the `includeJs` handler has fired, the `Craft.AuthManager` class has already been initialized and created the first timeout object. There's no reference to this timeout stored anywhere on the `Craft` object (that I've been able to find, at least), which makes it impossible to clear it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent for this code fragment in Craft 3 would be:

```php
        $view = Craft::$app->getView();
        $js = /** @lang JavaScript */
            <<< EOT
(function () {
    Craft.AuthManager.checkInterval = 600; // Ten minutes
}());
EOT;
        $view->registerJs($js, $view::POS_READY);
```

For reference:

```php
    /**
     * Registers a JS code block.
     * @param string $js the JS code block to be registered
     * @param int $position the position at which the JS script tag should be inserted
     * in a page. The possible values are:
     *
     * - [[POS_HEAD]]: in the head section
     * - [[POS_BEGIN]]: at the beginning of the body section
     * - [[POS_END]]: at the end of the body section
     * - [[POS_LOAD]]: enclosed within jQuery(window).load().
     *   Note that by using this position, the method will automatically register the jQuery js file.
     * - [[POS_READY]]: enclosed within jQuery(document).ready(). This is the default value.
     *   Note that by using this position, the method will automatically register the jQuery js file.
     *
     * @param string $key the key that identifies the JS code block. If null, it will use
     * $js as the key. If two JS code blocks are registered with the same key, the latter
     * will overwrite the former.
     */
```